# Regex to find matches from a string having multiple square brackets

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, regex, regex-group

I have a paragraph like below:

Some wording for testing [!#today] where the [!condition] does not satisfy with this verbiage **[!ShowElemIf://Student/FullName;  [[[Text not recognized fully]]]  ;/First Name]** But simple tags found having age [!ShowElemIf://Student/Age;xml//Student/DOB/@formatted;y]

I need to find all the placeholders/tags from above which are like: [!tag] using C#. I tried for a regex but it is not able to find the tag having "FullName" word as highlighted in bold above.

```js
List<string> tags = Regex.Matches(
                     sampleText.Replace(Environment.NewLine, ""), @"\[!([^]]+)\] ")
                     .Cast<Match>()
                     .Select(x => x.Groups[1].Value)
                     .ToList();
```

Using this RegEx I can find below but not the highlighted one.

1. today
2. condition
3. ShowElemIf://Student/Age;xml//Student/DOB/@formatted;y

Comment: Why do you have all that white space at the end of your pattern?

Comment: @juharr: I believe it is a quirk of Visual Studio, I have seen it already at SO, and also got the same issue yesterday when pasting text into my VS. It is just a copy/paste issue.

Comment: Yes. You may consider it as typo mistakes. Thanks@Wiktor for your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use  *balancing groups* available in .NET regex:

```
@"\[!((?:[^][]+|(?<o>\[)|(?<-o>)])*(?(o)(?!)))]"
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c%5b!%28%28%3f%3a%5b%5e%5d%5b%5d%2b%7c%28%3f%3co%3e%5c%5b%29%7c%28%3f%3c-o%3e%29%5d%29*%28%3f%28o%29%28%3f!%29%29%29%5d&i=Some+wording+for+testing+%5b!%23today%5d+where+the+%5b!condition%5d+does+not+satisfy+with+this+verbiage+%5b!ShowElemIf%3a%2f%2fStudent%2fFullName%3b+%5b%5b%5bText+not+recognized+fully%5d%5d%5d+%3b%2fFirst+Name%5d+But+simple+tags+found+having+age+%5b!ShowElemIf%3a%2f%2fStudent%2fAge%3bxml%2f%2fStudent%2fDOB%2f%40formatted%3by%5d)

**Details**:

- `\[!` - a `[!` substring
- `((?:[^][]+|(?<o>\[)|(?<-o>)])*(?(o)(?!)))` - Capturing group 1 matching

  - `(?:` - a non-capturing group with 3 alternatives:

    - `[^][]+|` - 1 or more chars other than `[` and `]`, or
    - `(?<o>\[)|` - a `[` pushed into "o" group stack, or
    - `(?<-o>)]` - a `]` is subtracted from the "o" group stack
  - `)*`  - zero or more occurrences
  - `(?(o)(?!)))` - a conditional construct checking if the "o" group stack is empty. If it is empty, matching goes on, else, no match is returned.
- `]`  - a literal closing `]` symbol.